# How to change volume name using cocoa on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, rename, volume, nsfilemanager

I am trying to change the name of the volume on a flash (USB) drive. I have tried different ways:

1. Disk Arbitration Framework
2. Just rename using NSFileManager

Thanks in advance,
Vladimir

Comment: What went wrong with the ways you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way would be to use `FSRenameUnicode`.